# AWS Lambda - How to Put ONNX Models in AWS Layers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, onnx, aws-lambda-layers

Currently, I have been downloading my ONNX models from S3 like so:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
if os.path.isfile('/tmp/model.onnx') != True:
    s3.download_file('test', 'models/model.onnx', '/tmp/model.onnx')
inference_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('/tmp/model.onnx')
```

However, I want to decrease the latency of having to download this model. To do so, I am looking to save the model in AWS Lambda layers. However, I'm having trouble doing so.

I tried creating a ZIP file as so:

```
- python
     - model.onnx
```

and loading it like `inference_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('/opt/model.onnx')` but I got a "File doesn't exist" error. What should I do to make sure that the model can be found in the `/opt/` directory?

Note: My AWS Lambda function is running on Python 3.6.

Comment: I'm curious. How did you install onnx on AWS Lambda? I am finding it difficult to do so.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use AWS Elastic Inference?

Comment: AWS Elastic Inference has been discontinued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file should be in `/opt/python/model.onnx`. Therefore, you should be able to use the following to get it:

```
inference_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('/opt/python/model.onnx')
```

If you don't want your file to be in `python` folder, then don't create layer with such folder. Just have `model.onnx` in the zip's root folder, rather then inside the `python` folder.